# Url with paramter as Button (Thymeleaf + Spring boot)

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm using Spring Boot and Thymeleaf. A button should display the user another page if he clicks on the Button. The only problem I have is, the url needs a parameter.

I tried this, but this doesn't work:

```
<form th:action="@{/removeserver(id=${serverId})}">
    <input  type="submit" value="Remove server"/>
</form>
```

It works with the following link, but not as button:

```
<a th:text="Remove" th:href="@{/removeserver(id=${serverId})}"></a>
```

So how can I display a url with a parameter as a button?

Comment: When you click on the link browser performs `GET` request, on other hand, when `form` submit data by default uses `POST` method. Add to your form `method="GET"` and your code should work.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem so instead of using path-variable I used request-param:

```
<form action="archive?id=${x.id}" method="post">
    <button type="submit">Archive</button>
</form>
```

You can try using this.

Comment: It doesn't work for me and how could this even work? You aren't using thymeleaf action for the variable.

Comment: Try this:
`<form th:action="@{/removeserver/{id}(id=${serverId})}">
    <input  type="submit" value="Remove server"/>
</form>
`